# How to show that X is connected ?

Tags: general-topology

Let ∼ be an equivalence relation on a topological space X such that
each equivalence class is connected and the quotient space X/ ∼ is
connected. Show that X is connected.

My  thinking that:  let $p\colon X \to Y$ be a quotient map  as  that if each set $p^{-1}({y})$ is connected, and if $Y$ is connected, then $X$ is connected.

I don't know the proper proof

Pliz help me

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433581/let-p-colon-x-to-y-be-a-quotient-map-then-if-each-set-p-1y-is-connec?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D = \{0,1\}$ be the two-point set with the discrete topology. 
A space $X$ is connected iff every continuous function to $D$ is constant, so apply that to our situation:

$q: X \to Y$ onto and quotient and let $f: X \to D$ be continuous.

For every $y \in Y$ the set $q^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is connected and so maps under $f$ to a single point of $D$ which I define to be $g(y)$. This defines a function $g: Y \to D$.

Note that $g \circ q = f$ (because in defining $g(q(x))$ we look at the fibre of $q(x)$ which contains $x$ which is mapped to $f(x)$ in $D$) and so by the universal mapping property of quotient maps $g$ is continuous because $f$ is.
Now, as $Y$ is connected $g$ is constant, and so $f$ is constant as well.

This shows $X$ is connected.

Comment: thanks  a lots Henno Brandsma,,for helping me